# Java 2d array with Icon names

Tags: java, icons, multidimensional-array

Do I can fill 2D array with icon file names like this? Im getting error that says

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Icon
```

So Question is, do imposible fill 2D array with icon file names, or I made small error here? I keep getting error only on array.

```
 public Icon cards[][] = {{"Diamonds 2.png", "Diamonds 3.png", "Diamonds 4.png", "Diamonds 5.png", "Diamonds 6.png", "Diamonds 7.png", "Diamonds 8.png",
                "Diamonds 9.png", "Diamonds 10.png", "Diamonds JACK.png", "Diamonds QUEEN.png", "Diamonds KING.png", "Diamonds ACE.png"},
                {"Hearts 2.png", "Hearts 3.png", "Hearts 4.png", "Hearts 5.png", "Hearts 6.png", "Hearts 7.png", "Hearts 8.png",
                "Hearts 9.png", "Hearts 10.png", "Hearts JACK.png", "Hearts QUEEN.png", "Hearts KING.png", "Hearts ACE.png"},
                {"Clubs 2.png", "Clubs 3.png", "Clubs 4.png", "Clubs 5.png", "Clubs 6.png", "Clubs 7.png", "Clubs 8.png",
                "Clubs 9.png", "Clubs 10.png", "Clubs JACK.png", "Clubs QUEEN.png", "Clubs KING.png", "Clubs ACE.png"},
                {"Spades 2.png", "Spades 3.png", "Spades 4.png", "Spades 5.png", "Spades 6.png", "Spades 7.png", "Spades 8.png",
                "Spades 9.png", "Spades 10.png", "Spades JACK.png", "Spades QUEEN.png", "Spades KING.png", "Spades ACE.png"}};
```

I have changed array name to check, maybe when im using it, that cause problem, but no, its same error on array.

Comment: You can either change array to be a string or change values to be of type Icon (new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);)

Comment: If I change it to String, then i cant use it as icon when I setting it on label. @Reimeus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you are creating a 2D array of strings.

So, change your 2D array definition to:

```
public String[][] cards = //...
```

Then, iterate over your 2D array, and load an icon for each string:

```
Icon[][] icons = new Icon[cards.length][];
for(int i=0;i<cards.length;i++){
    icons[i] = new Icon[cards[i].length];
    for(int j=0;j<cards[i].length;i++){
        icons[i][j] = //load icon from cards[i][j];
    }
}
```

And use the `icons` 2D array to set icons on your labels you mentioned in comments.